How do I use a custom git config file for a project through bitbucket?
I'm creating a custom sharedgitconfig file in one of the repositories of a project in bitbucket based on what I was able to read here. I'm a beginner, so please bear with me if these questions are fairly basic. The idea is that this repository will be cloned initially, and the developers will be able to use the infrastructure to make their changes to the code before using git aliases to automate some of the more tedious commands and naming schemes we have in place for things like Jenkins.
The issue I seem to be running into when I test with other developers is the constant need to include the custom config file in the path every time the repository is cloned. I understand that this is a requirement for the first time the repository is cloned as you have to set it up somehow, but is there a way to make this a one-time thing? Ideally this sort of configuration would only be used once when we first implement this into the project, and the developers will be able to use the aliases within without any hassle after.
Again, apologies if this is a bit of a redundant question. First time posting and haven't found much insight in the posts from 10+ years ago. Not for lack of trying.

I'm tempted to close this question as a duplicate of the one you referenced, because it might just be the case that you have to repeat the setup for every new clone. That being said, perhaps this question could be saved by referencing the other question and stating this is how to share configs with other users on a per repo basis, and then just asking something like, "Is there a way to make it automatic for new repos that aren't cloned yet?" Warning, if it is possible to do what you want, it could open a security risk for future untrusted repos that could alias commands automatically.

Truthfully, I'm running into new errors that weren't occurring yesterday, so I'll close the question on my own. When I manage to sort all that out, you'll probably see the revised version of this at some point. Thanks.

As you stated, yes, Git config is highly local to where it's cloned to; there isn't a good way to have git config propagate from remote repository to the local clone.
Solution 0
If you must, I would just have a shell script and have new developers run it:
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(git config setup.first) != didit ]]; then
    # Set up aliases
    git config alias.mycommand '!git something && git something-else'
    # Mark this as done so it doesn't run again
    # (Also allows devs to remove config if they desire, as long as this is set)
    git config setup.first didit
fi

This will modify <git clone dir>/.git/config adding an alias.
Solution 1: git mycommand actually executes git-mycommand
There's also a trick with git subcommands. When you run git foo, Git looks for a program called git-foo in the PATH and executes it. If you affect developer's PATH variables, you can have Git subcommands execute from an arbitrary directory.
#!/bin/bash
# Saved as /usr/bin/git-mycommand
git something && git something-else

Solution 1a: Same as solution 1, but using direnv
It might be possible to use direnv or something similar to affect this environment variable and add a directory with git-* scripts in it to the PATH.
For example when you have direnv set up and working on your local machine:
#!/bin/bash
# Saved as /usr/local/custom-git-commands/git-mycommand
git something && git something-else

# Saved as <git clone dir>/.envrc
PATH_add /usr/local/custom-git-commands

Then you can run git mycommand and it'll pick up /usr/local/custom-git-commands/git-mycommand and execute it.

I appreciate the response. Again, huge beginner here, so please correct me if I'm wrong, is this basically a shell script that's going to do the same things as git config --local include.path ../.gitconfig?
I'll have to look more into direnv, but it seems like it might be close to what I'm looking for.
One more note, would this script be ran every time the developers clone the repository? Not the end of the world if so, but the big reason we are trying to do this is to streamline the workflow.

FYI, I commented on the question that it's basically a dup of the referenced question, and this answer is another answer to that question, which is a subset of "Do X every time you clone a new repo." If we update this question as I suggested, this answer probably will no longer apply. (Though maybe it would apply to the other question.)
